# How to Save Login Session On Flutter Webview

Tags: flutter, flutter-dependencies

i have a flutter app with a webView to log in to a site, but i have a problem that every time the app close and reopen i need to login again.

Any thoughts?? Thank you

Tried to find solution to this, but to no avail, any thoughts? Thank you

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: have you checked `https://pub.dev/packages/shared_preferences`?